# How to playback a 5sec audio clip in a playlist every 5 songs?

Tags: php

This is basically my programming project looking at my friends script 
called:  Pickle Auto Playlist. Right now the script is using array_sort() = RND  for random...
and it generates or works with a playlist txt or xml file but its not as easy as editing the xml list. What would I need to look for and following steps to get this started and completed?

Here's the script my friend sent me if anyone knows. It prints a playlist and xml

http://pastebin.com/xN4jUVEe

Thanks so much for any tips.

Comment: That's a 1000 lines of code. You can't expect any of to go through all of it. Please post the relevant parts only.

Comment: To me I don't know which parts are pertaining to the custom goal of my friends script. But I can only Guess. Scroll down to where it shows: function array_sort   Thats one area that could affect this. Then function makePlaylist  or  this area which doesn't really pertain allow me to sort them to play 5secondaudioclip.mp3 after every 5th song as a copyright type of clip:  

// --- sortOrder
// Sets the sort order for files.
// Options: "ASC", "DEC", "RND"
//$sortOrder = "ASC";
$sortOrder = "RND";
//$sortOrder = "DEC";

Comment: Really sorry to hijack this post @pdnaegle, but as you have a mere 1 rep, you can neither comment, chat, nor post on Meta, so this is literally the only place to reach you. I came across [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15670526) of yours, which I rejected for one simple reason: You are not the author of the post. If you were, you could edit the question at once, without the edit having to be reviewed and approved first. Also note that reviewers are mere users, not any kind of staff, so we have no more information on your account(s) than is publicly accessible.

Answer (score 0):

Can't take credit, but Brian from our group (azphp.org) suggested using mod (%) and a counter to auto-inject your required item into the queue.

When starting out:

```
$counter = 0;
```

Every time you play a song:

```
$counter++;
if($counter % 5 == 0) { queue_the_ad(); $counter = 0; }
```

Comment: Whats the name of your group? Also I have no idea how that is done with modulo % and have never used it... I also have never customized much PHP but I am trying to learn, I only know foundations of OOP and PHP in this case but I do know setting conditionals with a counter but Where would I put this counter? Are you saying use something like this injected somewhere within a function thats created or if a class exists in there....

<?php
if ($counter % 2) {
echo "This number is not even.";
} else {
echo "This number is even.";
}
?>